# Android - How to copy a folder from File System to SD card using DDMS?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, ddms

I have a folder on the file system . 
The folder contains around **200 files**.
I want to copy this to a particular folder on SD card.

**The problem is** -

```
DDMS only gives the option of pushing a file onto device? 
Do we have any option of Pushing the complete folder onto device?
```

I know that there are ways to copy this folder programatically by keeping them in assets Or Zip the folder and copy it , but my question is specifically for `Android DDMS`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just push it  :-)

For example you have folder `/data/tmp` and you want to push it to `/mnt/sdcard`:

```
adb push /data/tmp /mnt/sdcard
```

Sorry I forgot you work with DDMS. But I just know how to do that with [`adb`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). You can find the file `adb` in folder `[android-sdk]/platform-tools/`. If you're running Windows, it could be `adb.bat` or `adb.exe`.

Comment: Thanks . But i want to know if it is possible through DDMS.

Comment: accepting the answer as this has helped me in completing the task.